# Problema con lectura de datos GPS con modulo SIM808

Tags: c++, arduino

Es estado intentando por mucho tiempo hacer funcionar mi modulo SIM808, tengo problemas al momento de leer los datos, ejecuta las funciones de encendido y parametrizacion correctamente, el problema esta al momento de leer los datos, ya que no me devuelve nada y el programa se detiene y deja de ejecutarse, como se observa en la imagen,tambien e notado que el el programa se reinica, es decir vuelve a pasar por el void setup();
Desde ya muchas gracias

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SIM808(7, 8);
int led = 13;
int ledStatus = LOW;
String campo[13];


void setup() {
  //
  SIM808.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Fin de setup");
  enviarAT("AT+GPSPWR=1","OK",1000);
  delay(500);

}

void decodeRespuesta(String r) {
  int ant = 0;
  int pos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
  {
    pos = r.indexOf(",", ant + 1);
    campo[i] = r.substring(ant, pos);
    ant = pos + 1;

  }

}

double DecodeNMEA(String l, String h) {
  int a = int(l.toFloat()) / 100;
  double b = (l.toFloat() - (a * 100)) / 60;
  if (h.equals("W") || h.equals("S")) {
    return (a + b) * -1;
  } else {
    return a + b;
  }
 // a=0;
 // b=0;
}

int enviarAT(String ATcommand, char* resp_correcta, unsigned int tiempo)
{

  int x = 0;
  bool correcto = 0;
  char respuesta[100];
  unsigned long anterior;

  memset(respuesta, '\0', 100); // Inicializa el string
  delay(100);
  while ( SIM808.available() > 0) SIM808.read(); // Limpia el buffer de entrada
  Serial.println(ATcommand);
  SIM808.println(ATcommand); // Envia el comando AT //Write
  //SIM808.flush();
  x = 0;
  anterior = millis();
  // Espera una respuesta
  do {
    // si hay datos el buffer de entrada del UART lee y comprueba la respuesta
    if (SIM808.available() != 0)
    {
      respuesta[x] = SIM808.read();
      x++;
      // Comprueba si la respuesta es correcta
      if (strstr(respuesta, resp_correcta) != NULL)
      {
        correcto = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Espera hasta tener una respuesta
  while ((correcto == 0) && ((millis() - anterior) < tiempo));
  //Serial.print("Respuesta: ");
  Serial.println(respuesta);

  return correcto;
}

String PushCoordenadas(){
  enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=32","OK",500);
  Serial.println("GPS Activado");
  delay(1000);

  //Serial.println(Serial.read());
  char lido = 0;
  String respuesta = "";
  while ((lido = SIM808.read()) != 10) {
    if (lido > 0) {
      respuesta += lido;
    }
    Serial.println("Leyendo: ");
    Serial.println(respuesta);
  }
  enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=1","OK",500);
  Serial.println("GPS Desactivado");

  delay(50);

  if (!respuesta.equals(" ")) {
    if (respuesta.indexOf("RMC") > 0)
    {
      Serial.println("RMC Detectado==========================================");

      enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=1","OK",3000);
      Serial.println("GPS Desactivado");
      delay(100);
      if (respuesta.charAt(18/*43*/) == 'A')
      {
        Serial.println("Dato util =A ");
        decodeRespuesta(respuesta);
        Serial.println(respuesta);
        for(int i=0;i<13;i++)Serial.println(campo[i]);

        Serial.print("Latitud: ");
        Serial.println(DecodeNMEA(campo[3], campo[4]), 10);
        Serial.print("Longitud: ");
        Serial.println(DecodeNMEA(campo[5], campo[6]), 10);


        ledStatus = HIGH;

        enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=1","OK",500);
        delay(600);
        Serial.println("GPS Desactivado");
        while (SIM808.read() <= 1);
        //SIM808.flush();


      } 
    }
  }


}

void loop() {
  PushCoordenadas();

 /* enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=32","OK",1000);
  delay(500);
  if(Serial.available()){
    Serial.print("Datos: ");
Serial.println(SIM808.read());

  }
 enviarAT("AT+CGPSOUT=1","OK",3000);
  delay(1000);*/


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se dónde se manifiesta el problema, dices "*al momento de leer los datos*" pero viendo tu programa no se dónde es. ¿No tienes un ejemplo más pequeño? ¿No tienes alguna manera de acotar el problema? Ayúdanos a ayudarte.

Comment: Si, el probelma esta en cuando invio los comandos AT correspondiente a la solicitud de los datos del GPS, este no me lee nada, es decir envio el comando AT, y espero la respuesta, pero al mostrar la respuesta, no se visualiza nada `Serial.println(respuesta); `Aqui deberia mostrase algo pero nada es visualizado, y al llegar a un cierto punto el programa se congela, exactamente en la posicion que se ve en la imagen anexa, y teoricamente se deberia de estar ejecutando una y otra vez